# Парсинг Python как убрать лишние символы из цены?

Tags: python, парсер

Собираю цены https://www.spokojenypes.cz/krmiva-pro-psy/, там где четырехзначные цены стоят доп. символы. При экспорте в csv получаются закорючки, пробовал убирать по разному но не убираются, при выделении цены на странице сайта, символы пропадают. Помогите разобраться с ними и убрать их. Вот скрины дебага и на сайте https://prnt.sc/25vwtsn , https://prnt.sc/25vxw24, https://prnt.sc/25vy12r

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    items = soup.find('div', class_='productBoxCat').find_all('div', class_='product-info')

    product_page = []
    for item in items:
        product_cost = item.find('a', class_='price-and-button-together').find('strong', class_='price_vat').get_text().split(' ')
        if len(product_cost) == 3:
            product_cost = item.find('a', class_='price-and-button-together').find('strong', class_='price_vat').get_text().split(' ')[0]
        else:
            product_cost = item.find('a', class_='price-and-button-together').find('strong', class_='price_vat').get_text().split('')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну это же символ `NO-BREAK SPACE`, в который переводится `&nbsp;` из `HTML`-я. Проще всего его просто заменить "вручную":

```
product_cost = product_cost.replace('\xa0', '')
```

Comment: спасибо, отличное решение, а я и не додумался про replace.

Answer (score 2):

Достаточно использовать метод `isdigit()`, чтобы отличать цифры от всего остального:

```py
new_product_cost = ''.join([char for char in product_cost if char.isdigit()])
```